# Low quality and weird ratio in game build in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

[image]
I'm not sure what I did wrong or what I changed, but for some reason the game build is now in this 3:4 or sth ratio and you can count the pixels.

Anyone ever had this?

I first noticed this after installing and using Post Pro, then rewinding through Git

I'm using the Standard Render Pipeline

Edit: Here are my Player Settings:
[image]

Comment: What's your Project Settings? (Edit > Project Settings > Player > Resolution & Presentation) https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettings.html

Comment: @Willard Peng I've added it to the post. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things you can try:

##### Wipe The **PlayerPrefs**

Somehow Unity picks up what's in the prefs rather
than the current settings, especially when using ***Native Resolution***.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class ResetPlayerPrefs : EditorWindow {
   [MenuItem("Edit/Reset Playerprefs)] 
   public static void DeletePlayerPrefs() {
       PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
    } 
}
```

Add this class to your project and then, in the Unity Editor, go to ***Edit -> Reset PlayerPrefs***.

Remember that Unity can only use resolutions that actually exist on the machine, unless in ***Windowed Mode***.

##### Delete Cached Settings

As it looks like you are running on a Mac, the window resolutions are cached in `~Library/Preferences`, you can try deleting the `.plist` file, then restarting the computer to make sure the cache gets wiped. Perhaps *Post Pro* mangled your cached settings.

##### Force the Aspect Ratio

You can force the game resolution at the start to ensure you desired aspect ratio, or cache the user's preference:

```
void Start()
{
    Screen.SetResolution(WIDTH, HEIGHT, IS_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your ideas! I tried everything, reseting player preferences didn't work for me and there was no Preferences directory in my Library folder :(
Forcing the Aspect Ratio did work but isn't really what I'm looking for
(I will still give you the bounty if no better answer show up :) )

Comment: I fixed the problem by upgrading to the URP, which I wanted to do whatsoever, but thanks for your contribution!